# Aesthetic Web Colors

Tags: css, colors, hex

What's a good resource for choosing aesthetically pleasing color combinations and themes? At the moment I'm using a color picker and stealing from various places. It's a hack.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- [Colour Lovers](http://www.colourlovers.com)
- [Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com/)
- [Color Jack](http://www.colorjack.com/sphere/)
- [Adobe Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/)
- [A study on Color Assignment](http://www.joehallock.com/edu/COM498/index.html)
- [A resource on Color Blindness](http://critiquewall.com/2007/12/10/blindness?printable)

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to throw something out there, but it's more important (IMO) to have a color scheme that promotes usability over one that is aesthetically pleasing. This resources on [Designing more Usable Web Sites](http://trace.wisc.edu/world/web/) might be of interest, along with [this blog posting](http://www.allwebdesignresources.com/webdesignblogs/graphics/webdesigncolorcombinationsguide/), which addresses both look AND usability.

Comment: People might say that, but if you design specifically for the color-blind, then audience wise you're designing for a fairly small group of people (10%, compared to say 90%).

Answer (score 1):

[ColorSchemer](http://www.colorschemer.com/online.html) - nice for finding complementary colors

Answer (score 0):

You can find some user-created color schemes on Kuler:

http://kuler.adobe.com

Answer (score 0):

I often use kuler.adobe.com. It is pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you find a page you like, you can find out the exact colors being used from "[I Like Your Colors](http://redalt.com/Tools/I+Like+Your+Colors)"